# Heap corruption c++ Function to return a table pointer

Tags: c++

I've got this problem with a program that I've been trying to solve by myself for days now and still don't know what exactly am I doing wrong. Could you please help? First I thought the fuss is all about the null at the end of the char table, but as you can see I fixed that and Visual Studio still tells me that I cause heap corruption somehow:

"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#186) at 0x02BAEC90.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

Thanks to all who wish to help a beginner in advance!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>  
using namespace std;  
#define T_SIZE 1001  
char* string_merge(char *, char *);  
int main()
{  
    int t,n;    
    char S1[T_SIZE], S2[T_SIZE], *S;    
    cin >> t; /* number of tests */   
    cin.getline(S1,T_SIZE);    
    while(t)
    {      
        cin.getline(S1,T_SIZE,' ');     
        cin.getline(S2,T_SIZE);           
        S=string_merge(S1,S2);     
        cout << S << endl;     
        delete[] S;     
        t--;      
    }    

    return 0; 

}

char * string_merge(char * n, char * k)
{
    char *Merged;
    char *n1;
    char *k1;
    n1 = n;
    k1 = k;
    if (strlen(n1) < strlen(k1))
    {
        const int length = (2*strlen(n1));

        Merged = new char[length+1];
        Merged[length] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0;i < (length);i++)
        {
            Merged[(2*i)] = *n1 ;
            Merged[(2*i) + 1] = *k1 ;
            if (i < (length - 1))
            {
                n1++;
                k1++;
            }


        }

    return Merged;

    }
    else
    {
        const int length = (2 * strlen(k1));
        Merged = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0;i < (length);i++)
        {
            Merged[(2 * i)] = *n1;
            Merged[(2 * i) + 1] = *k1;
            n1++;
            k1++;

        }
        Merged[length] = '\0';
        return Merged;

    }


}
```

Comment: Drop using `char` arrays and use `std::string` instead. That's what it is purposed for.

Comment: What do you think this does? `Merged[(2*i)]`

Comment: It's the representation of the index. I don't suppose that should be the problem. And I cannot use string for this task. I am supposed to write a function returning a pointer to a char table

Comment: *and I cannot use string for this task* -- But if you did use `std::string` in your environment (which is Visual C++), it would have pointed out to you your error as soon as you executed `Merged[(2*i)]`.  Also, if you printed out the values of `2*i` just for debugging purposes, you would see it is out-of-bounds.  As this is the case, [I downvoted because,,,](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You are right. Haven't thought that through. Thank you for your time and advice @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Topic considered closed

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the first string doesn't end with ' '?

Also after reading a number

```
cin >> t; /* number of tests */
```

you should ignore also the newline that was used to submit the number, so replace the first getline()

```
cin.getline(S1,T_SIZE);    
while(t) 
...
```

with

```
cin.ignore();
while(t) 
...
```

Comment: That was sadly not the case. The problem was inside the string_merge function and it has already been solved. Although you are right about that `cin.ignore();`